# WooCommerce: Missing products image's in admin dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

After last update of Woo I notice that products thumbnails in products section in admin dashboard are missing - I already checked screen options and regen all thumbnails - no effect.

Comment: I have the same problem. I haven't been able to figure out why it happens but reassigning the images to the products seems to bring the thumbnails and images back.

Comment: Please contact the plugin author